# Error saving a Task Group on TFS 2018.2 on prem

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Recently we've upgraded our TFS from 2017.1 to 2018.2

I have found a bug when saving a Task Group, when I click "Save" or "Save as draft", nothing happens and it throws an error to the browser console.

[image]

Comment: Did you try in another browser?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I tried both Chrome and Edge, on different versions.

Comment: Do you have permission to modify task groups?

Comment: @LeeKatsnelson What about creating a new task group then modify and save it? Just check if it has the same issue...